# What is the difference between object properties and object attributes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have seen two terms used with respect to objects in JavaScript, one is it's *property* and other is it's *attribute*. What are the differences between these terms?

> Each data property (object property that store data) has not only the name-value pair, but also 3 attributes (the three attributes are set to true by default):
>
> - **Configurable Attribute**: Specifies whether the property can be deleted or changed.
> - **Enumerable**: Specifies whether the property can be returned in a for/in loop.
> - **Writable**: Specifies whether the property can be changed.

<sub>Original context: http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-objects-in-detail/</sub>

Comment: Can you show us some context you're seeing it in? I'm guessing they're synonyms in this case.

Comment: It would depend on the precise context. Html elements have attributes (e.g. `document.getElementById("foo").attributes`), but if the author is referring to plain old JavaScript objects (e.g. `{foo:bar}`), then they're interchangeable.

Comment: [This](https://javascript.info/dom-attributes-and-properties) is more about HTML/DOM, but it will give you a feeling of difference between them

Answer (score 8):

What is Attribute and What is Property in Javascript?

In General, Both attribute and property are same. Both indicates Quality,in technical terms Key value pairs,So Key is the attribute/property's name and Value is nothing but it's Value.

What is the difference ?

Difference is the context not the meaning.

Why two terms are used ?

Because even a property of an Object may have property , which is termed as attribute.

what are Object's Attributes in Javascript?

Apart from Object's properties, Object has three attributes.
They are are *prototype*, *class*, and *extensible*

Ex :

```js
var SampleObject  = { Name : "ObjName", id : "0"} // user created
```

Actual Object's structure :

```js
         var SampleObject = {class :someValue, // Attribute
                    prototype : someValue, // Attribute
                    extensible : someValue, // Attribute
                    Name : "ObjName", // Property 
                    id : "0"   // Property 
                     }
```

what are Object's Properties in Javascript?

All the Key value pairs in the object are Object's Properties.

What are the attributes of all the Properties of an Object in JavaScript?

Every Property of an Object has the below 3 attributes.
*Configurable*, *Enumerable*, and *Writable* , The values are boolean.

```js
//Ex : 
var SampleObject = { key1 :{ p1 : "v1"}} // user created

//Actual Structure :

var SampleObject = { class :someValue, // Attribute
                     prototype : someValue, // Attribute
                     extensible : someValue, // Attribute
                     key1  : { Configurable : true, // attribute
                              Enumerable   : true, // attribute
                              Writable     : true  // attribute
                              p1           : "v1"  //property
                              }     // proeperty            
                   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Attributes are additional elements of the observed object.

Properties are characteristics of the observed object, are part of it.

In javascript these are interchangeable

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the author is not referring to attributes of an object, but attributes of a *property* (notice, as the author states, "*each data property … [has] 3 attributes*"). By this, he's referring to how the property itself behaves, usually with regards to built-in objects.

The author is correct that all three attributes are `true` by default when you create a property by simply assigning it like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = "bar";
```

Or in an object literal expression like this:

```
var obj = {foo:"bar"};
```

However, the author doesn't mention that you can use the `Object.defineProperty` method to modify these attributes. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Modifying_a_property) has a few examples that illustrate what attributes mean in practical terms.